# Ошибка Ivalue required as left operand of assignement

Tags: c

Нуждаюсь в вашей помощи. Хотел создать программу которая меняет местами четные
элементы  массива с нечетными. Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void citire (int* p, int n)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
     printf ("V[%i]=", i);  scanf ("%d", p+i);}
}  


void schimbare (int* p, int n)
{
int  i, buf;
if (n%2!=0) n--;

for (i=0; i<n; i+=2){
     buf= *(p+i);
     (p+i)=*(p+(i+1));
     (p+(i+1))=buf;}
 }

void afisare (int* p, int n)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
     printf ("V[%i]=%d", i, *(p+i));} 
}

int main ()
{
int V[10], dim;
printf ("Enter size of array:"); scanf ("%d", &dim);

citire (V,dim);
schimbare (V,dim);
afisare (V,dim);

return 0;
}
```

Kомпилятор выдает следующие ошибки:

In function 'void schimbare(int*, int)':
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: Ну так а что это такое `(p+(i+1))=buf`? Что вы этим пытались сделать? Вы не в состоянии без "помощи клуба" разглядеть в своем коде детскую опечатку? Которая к тому же просто бросается в глаза в сравнении с предыдущей строкой.

Comment: Таким способом я хотел значение переменой buf присвоить тому адресу

Comment: Что значит "присвоить значение адресу"??? У адреса уже есть значение - сам адрес. Это примерно как написать `5=2` и сказать, что "таким образом я хотел значению 5 присвоить значение 2".

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас программа компилируется, видимо мне еще надо разобраться с адресами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точно

```
 (p+i)=*(p+(i+1));
 (p+(i+1))=buf;}
```

Может, вы хотели

```
 *(p+i)=*(p+(i+1));
 *(p+(i+1))=buf;}
```

Ну вот чуть-чуть подумать, а?... Почему справа вы `*` ставите, а слева нет?